# Access shared preferences from broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have as SMS broadcast receiver. Basically I want to read the sender number and store it in shared preferences. How can I access the Shared preferences of my app from the broadcast receiver?

The only solution I found that maintains information between receivers would be use of global variable but I am not sure if this is right

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your shared preference from broadcast receiver like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = arg0.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 
                                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

**NOTE**

```
<receiver android:name="MySmsReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
```

If you are using `android:process=":remote"` then you might have to remove this. This attribute cause the receiver to run on a different/new process when it is called. But `SharedPreferences` is NOT supported between different processes.

As long as you are not doing big task in the receiver there isn't any issue with that.